# form-data prameters are sent in body, causing the getParameter method to return null

Tags: spring-boot, filter, null, servlet-filters, camunda

I've recently upgraded to the spring boot version 2.6.3 while using camunda 7.17.0. The login camunda page, sends a post request, but the form-data parameters are sent in the body, causing the getParameter method to return null.

I am implementing the class Filter for camunda login:

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
 throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest servletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    var param = servletRequest.getParameter(PARAMETER_KEY);
    //other things
}
```

but the parameter is returned as null.

Anyone knows how to solve it?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: well, I want to be able to apply the various login filters I've created to the specific user trying to login. But when I try to get the parameter thorugh servletRequest.getParameter("username") the method returns null, even though the parameter is sent.

I finally solved this the property spring.mvc.hiddenmethod.filter.enabled=true

Comment: Maybe add the answer to your question then

Answer (score 0):

Adding the property `spring.mvc.hiddenmethod.filter.enabled=true` in the application.properties file solved the issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).